# Are B.prototype = new A() and B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype) the same thing?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

Since `Object.create()` also returns a new object, are

`B.prototype = new A()`

and

`B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)`

the same thing? If not, what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not totally the same thing because when you do : `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)` you are creating an object B identical to the object A using the system constructor of the object. This method don't call the A() constructor.

But when you do `B.prototype = new A()` you are calling the constructor of the A element and you can get some other function/affectation in the constructor of A that can change the data in it.

Moreover the A() constructor can perform some checking and raise exception if condition are filled.

Fincally there are some difference in the two method.

Comment: Also, it is worth mentioning that `new A()` could possibly raise an exception from within the implementation whereas `Object.create( A.prototype )` will not execute the constructor at all, thus will not throw for the very same A.